# Glob for generating all permutations

Tags: perl, combinations, glob

I was using the following code to generate all the possible combinations of a permutation and store it in @apriorirow , This works correctly for small $globstring, but produces null @apriorirow for large inputs. How can I solve this problem?

```
$globstring = join ',', @distinctelements;
@apriorirow = glob "{$globstring}" x $i;

print "$globstring";
```

Comment: This would be easier to troubleshoot with a self-contained example. [perlfunc](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#glob) mentions that this is implemented by [File::Glob](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Glob), which mentions that it provides [a few error codes](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Glob#DIAGNOSTICS). Are those being set?

Comment: Perl has a few FAQ manpages: `perldoc -q permute` sends us to [`perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-permute-N-elements-of-a-list%3f) which offers a few solutions (in short: [Algorithm::Permute](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Permute))

Comment: @amon The OP is generating a Cartesian product (cross product), not a permutation. They just don't say what they mean :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are generating with `glob` is neither a combination nor a permutation, but a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (also known as the cross product). Storing the Cartesian product in an array will use a lot of memory for non-trivial input data. You can use [Set::CrossProduct](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set%3a%3aCrossProduct) to iterate through the Cartesian product one tuple at a time:

```
use Set::CrossProduct;

my $rows = 3;
my @elements = qw(a b c);

my @array;
push @array, \@elements for 1..$rows;

my $iterator = Set::CrossProduct->new(\@array);
while (my $tuple = $iterator->get) {
    say join ',', @$tuple;
}
```

#### Output:

```
a,a,a
a,a,b
a,a,c
a,b,a
a,b,b
a,b,c
a,c,a
a,c,b
a,c,c
b,a,a
b,a,b
b,a,c
b,b,a
b,b,b
b,b,c
b,c,a
b,c,b
b,c,c
c,a,a
c,a,b
c,a,c
c,b,a
c,b,b
c,b,c
c,c,a
c,c,b
c,c,c
```

Of course, you can also iterate with `glob`:

```
perl -wE 'say while glob "{a,b,c}" x 3'
```

will do essentially the same thing. But I find the intent clearer with Set::CrossProduct and prefer working with arrays instead of comma-delimited strings (not to mention the additional features Set::CrossProduct has like peeking at the next tuple without actually iterating).